Virtual Box Guru Meditation: A critical error occurred while running the virtual machine
I installed some months ago Virtual Box (ver 6.1.50_Ubuntu r161033) on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit with two virtual machines VM. After some months without any problem, I was trying to run a VM but a dialog window appeared saying that a critical error occurred, stopping the running of the VM and asking me to choose between switching it off or keeping it active in its state for debug purpose. I decided to turn it off. I tried also to run the second VM but I had the same problem.
I would like to share the entire logfile but I don't know how to attach it. This is the head of the log file:
00:00:00.908969 VirtualBox VM 6.1.50_Ubuntu r161033 linux.amd64 (Aug  2 2024 10:31:49) release log
00:00:00.908972 Log opened 2024-09-18T09:20:05.003024000Z
00:00:00.908972 Build Type: release
00:00:00.908979 OS Product: Linux
00:00:00.908980 OS Release: 6.8.0-40-generic
00:00:00.908981 OS Version: #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2
00:00:00.909006 DMI Product Name: NP5x_NP6x_NP7xRNJ_RNH
00:00:00.909012 DMI Product Version: Not Applicable
00:00:00.909019 Firmware type: UEFI
00:00:00.910309 Secure Boot: Enabled
00:00:00.910343 Host RAM: 64005MB (62.5GB) total, 61089MB (59.6GB) available
00:00:00.910346 Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM
00:00:00.910347 Process ID: 10392
00:00:00.910347 Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC (OSE)
00:00:00.917078 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:00.917089   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (Version: 6.1.50 r161033; VRDE Module: VBoxVRDP)
00:00:00.917093   VNC (Version: 6.1.50 r161033; VRDE Module: VBoxVNC)
00:00:00.918794 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:00.919312 Qt version: 5.15.3
00:00:00.919338 X11 Window Manager code: 4
00:00:00.936472 SUP: seg #0: R   0x00000000 LB 0x0004d000
00:00:00.936500 SUP: seg #1: R X 0x0004d000 LB 0x00120000
00:00:00.936506 SUP: seg #2: R   0x0016d000 LB 0x0005d000
00:00:00.936509 SUP: seg #3: RW  0x001ca000 LB 0x000350a8
00:00:00.942936 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:00.943496 X Server details: vendor: The X.Org Foundation, release: 12101004, protocol version: 11.0, display string: :0
00:00:00.943506 Using XKB for keycode to scan code conversion
00:00:00.944952 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (/usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0) at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - ModuleInit at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ModuleTerm at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:00.944964 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and VMMR0EntryFast at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:00.948489 Guest OS type: 'Windows11_64'
00:00:00.950402 GUI: UIDesktopWidgetWatchdog::sltHandleHostScreenAvailableGeometryCalculated: Screen 0 work area is actually resized to: 0x28 x 1920x1024
00:00:00.950985 fHMForced=true - No raw-mode support in this build!
00:00:00.968803 File system of '/home/eljamba/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 11/Windows 11.vdi' is ext4
00:00:00.973344 File system of '/home/eljamba/Scaricati/Win11_22H2_Italian_x64v2.iso' (DVD) is unknown
00:00:00.974407 Console: VM runtime error: fatal=false, errorID=DvdOrFloppyImageInaccessible message="The image file '/home/eljamba/Scaricati/Win11_22H2_Italian_x64v2.iso' is inaccessible and is being ignored. Please select a different image file for the virtual DVD drive."
00:00:01.007321 Shared Clipboard: Service loaded
00:00:01.007350 Shared Clipboard: Mode: Bidirectional
00:00:01.007425 Shared Clipboard: Service running in normal mode
00:00:01.009154 Drag and drop service loaded
00:00:01.009163 Drag and drop mode: Bidirectional
00:00:01.012960 GUI: Machine-window #0 activated
00:00:01.013002 GUI: Machine-view #0 focused, reason=3
00:00:01.013399 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
.....
00:00:01.014052 ********************* End of CFGM dump **********************

and this is the tail:
00:00:01.015278 HM: HMR3Init: VT-x w/ nested paging and unrestricted guest execution hw support
00:00:01.015367 MM: cbHyperHeap=0x2c0000 (2883584)
00:00:01.018244 CPUM: fXStateHostMask=0x7; initial: 0x7; host XCR0=0x207
00:00:01.026428 CPUM: Matched host CPU INTEL 0x6/0xba/0x2 Intel_Atom_Unknown with CPU DB entry 'Intel Pentium N3530 2.16GHz' (INTEL 0x6/0x37/0x8 Intel_Atom_Silvermont)
00:00:01.026676 CPUM: MXCSR_MASK=0xffff (host: 0xffff)
00:00:01.026690 CPUM: Microcode revision 0x00004121
00:00:01.026696 CPUM: Changing leaf 13[0]: EBX=0xa88 -> 0x340, ECX=0xa88 -> 0x340
00:00:01.026704 CPUM: MSR/CPUID reconciliation insert: 0x0000010b IA32_FLUSH_CMD
00:00:01.026706 CPUM: MSR/CPUID reconciliation insert: 0x0000010a IA32_ARCH_CAPABILITIES
00:00:01.026710 CPUM: MSR fudge: 0x00000122 IA32_TSX_CTRL
00:00:01.027130 PGM: Host paging mode: AMD64+PGE+NX
00:00:01.027143 PGM: PGMPool: cMaxPages=8448 (u64MaxPages=8240)
00:00:01.027146 PGM: pgmR3PoolInit: cMaxPages=0x2100 cMaxUsers=0x4200 cMaxPhysExts=0x2000 fCacheEnable=true 
00:00:01.028553 PGM: /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count = 65530 (rc2=VWRN_TRAILING_CHARS); cGuessNeeded=16384
00:00:01.058867 TM: GIP - u32Mode=3 (Invariant) u32UpdateHz=100 u32UpdateIntervalNS=10000000 enmUseTscDelta=3 (Roughly Zero) fGetGipCpu=0x1b cCpus=20
00:00:01.058884 TM: GIP - u64CpuHz=2 918 399 887 (0xadf33f8f)  SUPGetCpuHzFromGip => 2 918 399 887
.....
00:00:01.058995 TM: cTSCTicksPerSecond=2 918 399 887 (0xadf33f8f) enmTSCMode=1 (VirtTscEmulated)
00:00:01.058997 TM: TSCTiedToExecution=false TSCNotTiedToHalt=false
00:00:01.060142 EMR3Init: fIemExecutesAll=false fGuruOnTripleFault=true 
00:00:01.060987 IEM: TargetCpu=CURRENT, Microarch=Intel_Atom_Unknown
00:00:01.060987 GIM: Using provider 'HyperV' (Implementation version: 0)
00:00:01.060987 GIM: HyperV: Reporting vendor as 'VBoxVBoxVBox'
00:00:01.060987 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled Hypervisor Present bit
00:00:01.082067 AIOMgr: Default manager type is 'Async'
00:00:01.082101 AIOMgr: Default file backend is 'NonBuffered'
00:00:01.082475 BlkCache: Cache successfully initialized. Cache size is 5242880 bytes
00:00:01.082477 BlkCache: Cache commit interval is 10000 ms
00:00:01.082478 BlkCache: Cache commit threshold is 2621440 bytes
.....
00:00:01.176499 HM: Supports VMCS EFER fields         = true 
00:00:01.176500 HM: Enabled VMX
00:00:01.176509 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled SYSENTER/EXIT
00:00:01.176510 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled PAE
00:00:01.176510 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled LONG MODE
00:00:01.176511 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled SYSCALL/RET
00:00:01.176511 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled LAHF/SAHF
00:00:01.176511 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled NX
00:00:01.176512 HM: Enabled nested paging
00:00:01.176512 HM:   EPT flush type                  = Single context
00:00:01.176512 HM: Enabled unrestricted guest execution
00:00:01.176513 HM: Enabled VPID
00:00:01.176513 HM:   VPID flush type                 = Single context
00:00:01.176513 HM: Enabled VMX-preemption timer (cPreemptTimerShift=7)
00:00:01.176514 HM: VT-x/AMD-V init method: Global
00:00:01.176515 EM: Exit history optimizations: enabled=true  enabled-r0=true  enabled-r0-no-preemption=false
00:00:01.176543 APIC: fPostedIntrsEnabled=false fVirtApicRegsEnabled=false fSupportsTscDeadline=false
00:00:01.176548 TMR3UtcNow: nsNow=1 726 651 205 270 612 000 nsPrev=0 -> cNsDelta=1 726 651 205 270 612 000 (offLag=0 offVirtualSync=0 offVirtualSyncGivenUp=0, NowAgain=1 726 651 205 270 613 000)
00:00:01.176556 VMM: fUsePeriodicPreemptionTimers=false
00:00:01.176567 APIC: Enabling Hyper-V x2APIC compatibility mode
00:00:01.178645 CPUM: Logical host processors: 20 present, 20 max, 20 online, online mask: 00000000000fffff
00:00:01.178818 CPUM: Physical host cores: 14
00:00:01.178819 ************************* CPUID dump ************************
00:00:01.178829          Raw Standard CPUID Leaves
00:00:01.178829      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
......
00:00:01.178911                                Name: GenuineIntel
00:00:01.178912                            Supports: 0x00000000-0x00000016
00:00:01.178913                              Family:  6     Extended: 0     Effective: 6
00:00:01.178914                               Model: 10     Extended: 11    Effective: 186
00:00:01.178915                            Stepping: 2
00:00:01.178916                                Type: 0 (primary)
00:00:01.178916                             APIC ID: 0x00
00:00:01.178917                        Logical CPUs: 12
00:00:01.178918                        CLFLUSH Size: 8
00:00:01.178918                            Brand ID: 0x00
00:00:01.178919 Features
00:00:01.178920   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:01.178920   FPU - x87 FPU on Chip                                   = 1 (1)
.....
00:00:01.179001 Processor Extended State Enumeration (leaf 0xd):
00:00:01.179004    XSAVE area cur/max size by XCR0, guest: 0x340/0x340
00:00:01.179004     XSAVE area cur/max size by XCR0, host: 0xa88/0xa88
00:00:01.179005                    Valid XCR0 bits, guest: 0x00000000`00000007 ( x87 SSE YMM_Hi128 )
00:00:01.179007                     Valid XCR0 bits, host: 0x00000000`00000207 ( x87 SSE YMM_Hi128 9 )
00:00:01.179009                     XSAVE features, guest:
00:00:01.179009                      XSAVE features, host: XSAVEOPT XSAVEC XGETBC1 XSAVES
00:00:01.179011       XSAVE area cur size XCR0|XSS, guest: 0x680
00:00:01.179011        XSAVE area cur size XCR0|XSS, host: 0x680
00:00:01.179012                Valid IA32_XSS bits, guest: 0x00000000`00000000
00:00:01.179012                 Valid IA32_XSS bits, host: 0x00019900`00000000 ( 40 43 44 47 48 )
00:00:01.179014   State #2, guest: off=0x0240, cb=0x0100 IA32_XSS-bit -- YMM_Hi128
00:00:01.179015   State #2, host:  off=0x0240, cb=0x0100 IA32_XSS-bit -- YMM_Hi128
00:00:01.179018   State #8, host:  off=0x0000, cb=0x0080 XCR0-bit -- 8
00:00:01.179019   State #9, host:  off=0x0a80, cb=0x0008 IA32_XSS-bit -- 9
00:00:01.179020   State #11, host:  off=0x0000, cb=0x0010 XCR0-bit -- 11
00:00:01.179021   State #12, host:  off=0x0000, cb=0x0018 XCR0-bit -- 12
00:00:01.179023   State #15, host:  off=0x0000, cb=0x0328 XCR0-bit -- 15
00:00:01.179024   State #16, host:  off=0x0000, cb=0x0008 XCR0-bit -- 16
00:00:01.179030          Unknown CPUID Leaves
00:00:01.179030      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
.....
00:00:01.179036          Raw Hypervisor CPUID Leaves
00:00:01.179036      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
.....
00:00:01.179044          Raw Extended CPUID Leaves
00:00:01.179044      Leaf/sub-leaf  eax      ebx      ecx      edx
.....
00:00:01.179072 Ext Name:                        
00:00:01.179072 Ext Supports:                    0x80000000-0x80000008
00:00:01.179073 Family:                          0      Extended: 0     Effective: 0
00:00:01.179073 Model:                           0      Extended: 0     Effective: 0
00:00:01.179074 Stepping:                        0
00:00:01.179074 Brand ID:                        0x000
00:00:01.179075 Ext Features
00:00:01.179075   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:01.179076   FPU - x87 FPU on Chip                                   = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179076   VME - Virtual 8086 Mode Enhancements                    = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179077   DE - Debugging extensions                               = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179078   PSE - Page Size Extension                               = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179079   TSC - Time Stamp Counter                                = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179079   MSR - K86 Model Specific Registers                      = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179080   PAE - Physical Address Extension                        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179081   MCE - Machine Check Exception                           = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179082   CX8 - CMPXCHG8B instruction                             = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179082   APIC - APIC On-Chip                                     = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179083   SEP - SYSCALL/SYSRET                                    = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179084   MTRR - Memory Type Range Registers                      = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179085   PGE - PTE Global Bit                                    = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179085   MCA - Machine Check Architecture                        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179086   CMOV - Conditional Move instructions                    = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179087   PAT - Page Attribute Table                              = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179088   PSE-36 - 36-bit Page Size Extension                     = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179088   NX - No-Execute/Execute-Disable                         = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179089   AXMMX - AMD Extensions to MMX instructions              = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179090   MMX - Intel MMX Technology                              = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179090   FXSR - FXSAVE and FXRSTOR Instructions                  = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179091   FFXSR - AMD fast FXSAVE and FXRSTOR instructions        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179092   Page1GB - 1 GB large page                               = 0 (1)
00:00:01.179092   RDTSCP - RDTSCP instruction                             = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179093   LM - AMD64 Long Mode                                    = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179094   3DNOWEXT - AMD Extensions to 3DNow                      = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179095   3DNOW - AMD 3DNow                                       = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179096   LahfSahf - LAHF/SAHF support in 64-bit mode             = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179096   CmpLegacy - Core multi-processing legacy mode           = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179097   SVM - AMD Secure Virtual Machine extensions             = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179098   EXTAPIC - AMD Extended APIC registers                   = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179098   CR8L - AMD LOCK MOV CR0 means MOV CR8                   = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179099   ABM - AMD Advanced Bit Manipulation                     = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179100   SSE4A - SSE4A instructions                              = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179100   MISALIGNSSE - AMD Misaligned SSE mode                   = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179101   3DNOWPRF - AMD PREFETCH and PREFETCHW instructions      = 1 (1)
00:00:01.179102   OSVW - AMD OS Visible Workaround                        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179102   IBS - Instruct Based Sampling                           = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179103   XOP - Extended Operation support                        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179104   SKINIT - SKINIT, STGI, and DEV support                  = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179104   WDT - AMD Watchdog Timer support                        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179105   LWP - Lightweight Profiling support                     = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179106   FMA4 - Four operand FMA instruction support             = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179106   NodeId - NodeId in MSR C001_100C                        = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179107   TBM - Trailing Bit Manipulation instructions            = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179108   TOPOEXT - Topology Extensions                           = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179108   PRFEXTCORE - Performance Counter Extensions support     = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179109   PRFEXTNB - NB Performance Counter Extensions support    = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179110   DATABPEXT - Data-access Breakpoint Extension            = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179110   PERFTSC - Performance Time Stamp Counter                = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179111   PCX_L2I - L2I/L3 Performance Counter Extensions         = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179111   MWAITX - MWAITX and MONITORX instructions               = 0 (0)
00:00:01.179112 Full Name:                       "13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700H"
.....
00:00:01.179133 Physical Address Width:          39 bits
00:00:01.179133 Virtual Address Width:           48 bits
00:00:01.179133 Guest Physical Address Width:    0 bits
00:00:01.179134 Physical Core Count:             1
00:00:01.179135 
00:00:01.179136 ******************** End of CPUID dump **********************
00:00:01.179136 *********************** VT-x features ***********************
00:00:01.179137 Nested hardware virtualization - VMX features
00:00:01.179138   Mnemonic - Description                                  = guest (host)
00:00:01.179138   VMX - Virtual-Machine Extensions                        = 0 (1)
.....
00:00:01.179166 ******************* End of VT-x features ********************
00:00:01.179194 VMEmt: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:01.179408 VMEmt: HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=2000
00:00:01.179950 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'
00:00:01.183797 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'
00:00:01.184054 AIOMgr: Endpoints without assigned bandwidth groups:
00:00:01.184069 AIOMgr:     /home/eljamba/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 11/Windows 11.vdi
00:00:01.184430 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:01.184434 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:01.186026 EFI: debug point SEC_PREMEM
00:00:01.187230 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'
00:00:01.187244 Console: Machine state changed to 'GuruMeditation'
00:00:01.187486 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:01.187486 !!
00:00:01.187486 !!         VCPU0: Guru Meditation -2708 (VERR_VMM_SET_JMP_ABORTED_RESUME)
00:00:01.187501 !!
00:00:01.187513 !! ACTIVE TRAP=0e ERRCD=2 CR2=0000000002200000 PC=00000000fffcd79a Type=0 cbInstr=ff fIcebp=false (Guest!)
00:00:01.187520 !!
00:00:01.187520 !! CallRing3JmpBuf:
00:00:01.187521 !!

00:00:01.212398 usb-xhci#0: PCI MMIO=ffffffffffffffff IRQ=0 MSI=off R0=true  RC=false
00:00:01.212404 USBCMD: 0:
00:00:01.212406 USBSTS: 1: HCH
00:00:01.212407 DNCTRL: 0   CONFIG: 0 (0 slots)
00:00:01.212410 DCBAA ptr: 0000000000000000
00:00:01.212411 CRCR ptr : 0000000000000000
00:00:01.212413 Port 01 (USB2): PORTSC:    206A1: CCS PLS=5 PP SPD=1 CSC
00:00:01.212419 Port 02 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212422 Port 03 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212425 Port 04 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212427 Port 05 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212430 Port 06 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212432 Port 07 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212434 Port 08 (USB2): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212437 Port 09 (USB3): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212439 Port 10 (USB3): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212442 Port 11 (USB3): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212444 Port 12 (USB3): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212447 Port 13 (USB3): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212449 Port 14 (USB3): PORTSC:      2A0: PLS=5 PP SPD=0
00:00:01.212466 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:01.212604 emR3Debug: rc=VERR_VMM_SET_JMP_ABORTED_RESUME
00:00:07.768294 GUI: User request to power VM off on Guru Meditation.
00:00:07.768332 GUI: Passing request to power VM off from machine-logic to UI session.
00:00:07.768338 GUI: Powering VM down on UI session power off request...
00:00:07.768707 Console: Machine state changed to 'Stopping'
00:00:07.769599 Console::powerDown(): A request to power off the VM has been issued (mMachineState=Stopping, InUninit=0)
00:00:07.770562 Changing the VM state from 'GURU_MEDITATION' to 'POWERING_OFF'
00:00:07.770605 ****************** Guest state at power off for VCpu 11 ******************
......
00:00:07.772472 ************** End of Guest state at power off ***************
00:00:07.791901 PDMR3PowerOff: 19 388 935 ns run time
00:00:07.791920 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_OFF' to 'OFF'
00:00:07.794105 Changing the VM state from 'OFF' to 'DESTROYING'
00:00:07.794477 ************************* Statistics *************************
......
00:00:07.796858 ********************* End of statistics **********************
00:00:07.837205 GIM: HyperV: Resetting MMIO2 regions and MSRs
00:00:07.849756 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'
00:00:07.863972 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:08.692012 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 1366x625
00:00:08.692126 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up (setVideoModeHint)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:08.692247 GUI: Passing request to close Runtime UI from machine-logic to UI session.
00:00:08.692267 GUI: Aborting startup due to invalid machine state detected: 1

The logfile contains an error regarding the missing iso file which doesn't actually describe this problem. I used the VM after having moved the .iso file and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure, but in my opinion the error appears for the first time here:
00:00:01.187486 !!         VCPU0: Guru Meditation -2708 (VERR_VMM_SET_JMP_ABORTED_RESUME)

I tried to update VirtualBox downloading the .deb package from the VirtualBox download page. Once I run the package, I got these two errors:

Conflicts with the installed package virtualbox-dkms

Conflicts with the installed package virtualbox-qt


Currently, I am running a Linux kernel version: 6.8.0-45-generic.
How to solve the problem and make the VM executable?

This question is similar to: Guru Meditation on Virtualbox. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I read that question which is for sure similar with the exception that regards a different Ubuntu distribution (22.04 vs 20.04). The different distribution could be also not relevant to this problem. It is arguable to say how similar they are because the Logfile he copied is so short, so it is difficult to me to understand if we had exactly the same problem. He solved upgrading Virtualbox. I will use this solution in case of absence of other suggestions. I'm afraid that upgrading Virtualbox could worsen the problem making the Virtual machines inaccessible.

I don't mind retracting my close vote if you tried the duplicate question and it didn't work.

I solved uninstalling the packages (dkms, qt, guest-utils) with these commands:
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-qt
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-utils

Then the update of virtualbox (downloaded from its website) was successfully installed and the VMs returned to be executable.
Currently, I'm running the Virtualbox version 7.1.2 r164945 (Qt6.5.3) with Linux kernel 6.8.0-45-generic on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I fixed the "VirtualBox Guru meditation" error in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS removing guest-additions too, so the complete sequence is as follows:
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-qt
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-utils
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

I then downloaded the VirtualBox version 7.x software package from VirtualBox-downloads and installed it with GDebi. You may instead add an apt source, as the documentation suggests, and then install Virtualbox using:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-7.1

Virtual machines that had failed to start with version 6.x, could now be launched, although their original state was lost.
